# Merging multiple dataframes with non unique indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, pandas, merge

Given two DFs with non unique indexes and multidimentional columns:

ars:

```
           arsenal   arsenal   arsenal   arsenal
NaN             B3        SK        BX        BY
2015-04-15     NaN       NaN       NaN      26.0
2015-04-14     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-04-13    26.0      26.0      23.0       NaN
2015-04-13    22.0      21.0      19.0       NaN
```

che:

```
           chelsea   chelsea   chelsea   chelsea
NaN             B3        SK        BX        BY
2015-04-15     NaN       NaN       NaN      1.01
2015-04-14    1.02       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-04-14     NaN      1.05       NaN       NaN
```

here in csv format

```
,arsenal,arsenal,arsenal,arsenal
,B3,SK,BX,BY
2015-04-15,,,,26.0
2015-04-14,,,,
2015-04-13,26.0,26.0,23.0,
2015-04-13,22.0,21.0,19.0,
```

---

```
,chelsea,chelsea,chelsea,chelsea
,B3,SK,BX,BY
2015-04-15,,,,1.01
2015-04-14,1.02,,,
2015-04-14,,1.05,,
```

I would like to join/merge them, sort of an outer join so that rows are not dropped.

I would like the output to be:

```
            arsenal  arsenal   arsenal   arsenal chelsea   chelsea   chelsea   chelsea
NaN             B3        SK        BX        BY      B3        SK        BX        BY
2015-04-15     NaN       NaN       NaN      26.0     NaN       NaN       NaN      1.01
2015-04-14     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN    1.02       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-04-14     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN      1.05       NaN       NaN
2015-04-13    26.0      26.0      23.0       NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2015-04-13    22.0      21.0      19.0       NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

None of the pandas tools I know worked: `merge`, `join`, `concat`. merge's outer join gives a dot product which is not what I am looking for, while `concat` can't handle non unique indexes.

Do you have any ideas how this can be achieved?

Note: the lengths of dataframes won't be idential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to sort it out using pandas' `concat` method.

First, we need to add a Multiindex level so that it becomes unique:

```
ars = pd.read_csv("ars.csv", index_col=[0], header=[0,1])
che = pd.read_csv("che.csv", index_col=[0], header=[0,1])

ars.index.name = "date"
ars["num"] = range(0, len(ars.index))
ars = ars.set_index("num", append=True)

che.index.name = "date"
che["num"] = range(0, len(che.index))
che = che.set_index("num", append=True)
```

Now we can use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([ars, che], axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_index(by=["date", "num"], ascending=[False, True])
df = df.set_index(["date", "num"])
df.index = df.index.droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
                arsenal             chelsea                
                B3  SK  BX  BY      B3    SK  BX    BY
date                                                  
2015-04-15     NaN NaN NaN  26     NaN   NaN NaN  1.01
2015-04-14     NaN NaN NaN NaN    1.02   NaN NaN   NaN
2015-04-14     NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN  1.05 NaN   NaN
2015-04-13      26  26  23 NaN     NaN   NaN NaN   NaN
2015-04-13      22  21  19 NaN     NaN   NaN NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `on='outer'` argument for `join` (`test1.csv` and `test2.csv` are the files you gave):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1])

df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

This is the result I get:

```
           arsenal             chelsea  
                B3  SK  BX  BY      B3    SK  BX    BY
2015-04-13      26  26  23 NaN     NaN   NaN NaN   NaN
2015-04-14     NaN NaN NaN NaN    1.02   NaN NaN   NaN
2015-04-14     NaN NaN NaN NaN     NaN  1.05 NaN   NaN
2015-04-15     NaN NaN NaN  26     NaN   NaN NaN  1.01
```

Comment: Hi, thx for input. It did work in this example, where the lengths of frames were indential. However, it's not guaranteed in my case.

Comment: I tried it with different numbers of rows and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(ars, che, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'outer')
```

It can handle non-unique index and different size of the dataframes.

Comment: Thanks! I set the left & right index parameters to True and got the results I needed.