# Naturally sorting pandas data rasies error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, natsort

I have a pandas data from with the following indices

```
print(df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Day 3', u'Day 4', u'Day 5', u'Day 7', u'Day 9'], [u'D1', u'D10', u'D11', u'D12', u'D2', u'D3', u'D4', u'D5', u'D6', u'D7', u'D8', u'D9'], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]],
       labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]],
       names=[u'Interval', u'Device', u'Well'])
```

I am sorting with the following

```
 df = df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))
```

With this particular df, however, it returns the follow error.

```
raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? meaning a script I can copy / past and run locally.

Comment: That's difficult to do because data is being read into pandas from a series of excel files.  I was hoping I was missing something obvious

Comment: Please see my example and comment if it fits your input data.

Comment: I imagine that this has nothing to do with `natsort`.  If your last line is `df = df.reindex(index=df.index)` do you get the same error? Or `df = df.reindex(index=sorted(df.index))`? If that is the case,  your title is misleading.  Probably it should be renamed to "Error reindexing pandas data frame" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a minimal example and could reproduce your error. It seems it happens, because of the same levels tuple `Day 3, D1 and 1.0` in `arrays`. If you remove one of them it works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from natsort import natsorted

arrays = [[u'Day 3', u'Day 3', u'Day 4', u'Day 5', u'Day 7', u'Day 9', u'Day 3', u'Day 4', u'Day 5', u'Day 7', u'Day 9'],
          [u'D1',    u'D1',    u'D10',   u'D11',   u'D12',   u'D2',    u'D3',    u'D4',    u'D5',    u'D6',    u'D7'],
          [1.0,      1.0,      2.0,      3.0,      1.0,      2.0,      1.0,      2.0,      3.0,      1.0,      2.0]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[u'Interval', u'Device', u'Well'])
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(arrays[0])), index=index)

print df.index

df = df.reindex(index=natsorted(df.index))
```

As you mentioned you use several excel files, this may be helpful: [Merging multiple dataframes with non unique indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656155/merging-multiple-dataframes-with-non-unique-indexes)